# Gerrit LDAP Configuration

Tags: ldap, gerrit

I am configuring gerrit over Windows server 2008 R2 along with mysql and tomcat.

I have completed installation successfully. Authentication mode is LDAP.

I am unable to login. The error is:

```
com.google.gerrit.server.account.AccountManager: Cannot assign user name "XXXXXX" to account 8; name does not conform.
```

In my case user name contains digits, while I came to know that gerrit doesn't allow to login if all the letters are digit in username [Gerrit Google Group Discussion](https://code.google.com/p/gerrit/issues/detail?id=1564)

Please guide me what should I configure or what can be the solution to this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I got the solution. Gerrit doesn't allow user name to be all digits. So all you gotta do is some config changes in gerrit.config under ldap section.

Under ldap section put:

```
accountPattern = (&(objectClass=person)(mail=${username}))
accountSshUserName = ${givenName}.${sn}
```

Now you will be able to login using your mail id and user information stored will be firstname.lastname.

Cheerss!!!